# Integral involving the CDF of normal distribution from a to b

Tags: probability-distributions, definite-integrals, normal-distribution

I am doing some research and got stuck in solving the following integral (which I am not sure whether it has a closed form solution or not, I hope it has:))
Here is the integral:

$$ \int_{l}^{h} {e^{-(x-a)^2}N(cx+d)dx}$$
where $N(x) =\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty }^{x} {e^{-z^2/2}dz}$

Especially, I am particularly interested in the special case:
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{h} {e^{-(x-a)^2}N(cx+d)dx}$$

Here are other two similar questions as far as I know: [link1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/414355/integral-involving-the-cdf-of-normal-distribution) and [link2](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61080/how-can-i-calculate-int-infty-infty-phi-left-fracw-ab-right-phiw),they are special cases where $l = -\infty$ and $h = +\infty$.

Any help would greatly be appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hint: I am using the notation from the links. The case $\phi(x-a)$ is easily
rewritten as
\begin{align}
&\int_\ell^h\phi(x)\Phi(cx+d)\,dx=\mathbb P\Big\{\ell<X<h,Y< cX+d\Big\}\\
&=\mathbb P\Big\{\ell<X<h,Z< d\Big\}
\end{align}
where $X$ and $Y$ are independent and $Z=Y-cX\,.$ Now figure out the variance of $Z$ and the covariance of
$X$ and $Z\,.$ Then the final probability is a matter for the bivariate normal CDF.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Indeed, my question has been solved by the bivariate normal CDF.