# How do we get this approximation

Tags: statistics, proof-writing

Show the following relationship:
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi(\lambda x) N(x | \mu, \sigma^2) \, dx = \Phi\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{\lambda^{-2} + \sigma^2}}\right)$
Hint: One way to solve this is to use the definition of $Phi(x) = P[Z \leq x]$.

I have gotten to the point in the Bayesian logistic regression where the integral of the probability distribution is only solvable as this inverse probit. I started off by writing the LHS in full $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \left( \int_{-\infty}^{\lambda x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \exp\left(-\frac{u^2}{2}\right) du \right) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \, dx$

I expect to do some change of variable to convolute the exponentials but can't quite see what to do next.

Comment: Follow this [hint](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4859626/integral-involving-the-cdf-of-normal-distribution-from-a-to-b#comment10359239_4859626).

Answer (score 0):

Let $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$ independent of $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Then
$$\Pr(Y \leqslant \lambda X) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Pr(Y \leqslant \lambda x) N(x | \mu, \sigma^2) \, dx = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi(\lambda x) N(x | \mu, \sigma^2) \, dx.$$
Now, $Y - \lambda X \sim \mathcal{N}(-\lambda\mu, 1 + \lambda^2\sigma^2)$ has *cdf* $\Phi\left(\frac{\cdot \, + \lambda\mu}{\sqrt{1 + \lambda^2\sigma^2}}\right)$, hence
$$\Pr(Y \leqslant \lambda X) = \Pr(Y - \lambda X \leqslant 0) = \Phi\left(\frac{\lambda\mu}{\sqrt{1+\lambda^2\sigma^2}}\right),$$
and this is equal to the annouced result.